# Google speech-to-text is missing out few sentences in the transcript for hindi, telugu audios, why?

Tags: google-speech-to-text-api

I tried Google speech-to-text for few hindi and telugu phone calls. It's missing out few sentences in the transcript. In the below image, we can see that `01:52 - 02:01` and `01:52 - 02:01` etc parts are missed in the transcript. I am facing same issue irrespective of any format audio (mp3, wav, stereo, mono).

Looks like it is giving only the parts where confidence>0.8 . But I didn't set that confidence threshold anywhere while in the console config while generating. So, is there any way where I can get the transcript without missing parts in it?[image]

Comment: Are you using the `phone_call` transcription model? Did you try using any other models?

Comment: If possible, can you share the audio file that gives partial transcriptions?

Comment: You can get your own phone call audio data, using call recording on your phone, or using free trial of cloud phone management services like servetel, twilio etc.

Comment: I used Twilio to get some phone call recordings for transcription. The STT API gave the complete transcription. I'm asking for the audio files because the results may vary based on how intelligible the audio files are.

Comment: Are you facing this issue with all the files you have tested?

Comment: Yes, Im getting this issue for all hindi audios.

Comment: Hello, this issue will have to be looked into further. So, can you please create a confidential issue using this [template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491447&template=1161074), and share the audio files so that the root cause can be identified.